# Finding the neighbourhood of certain pixels

Tags: matlab, nan, neighbours

I have an image which matrix has some pixels with value `NaN`. For such certain pixel, I want to compare its `8-neighbourhood`, and assign it a value based on that neighborhood.

I think for the neighbourhood we use `nlfilter`?

How can I do that in `matlab`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could decide by [`isnan`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/isnan.html), e.g.

```
M = nlfilter(M, [3,3], @neighFun);

function ret = neighFun(x)
    if isnan(x(2,2))
        ret = whatever;
    else
        ret = x(2,2);
    end
end
```

Comment: @matheburg.Thanks for your reply. What does `@` preceding the function name mean?

Comment: @neighFun is a [function handle](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/function_handle.html). That means you hand over a reference to neighFun to nlfilter. Without "@" it would try to call neighFun and hand over the return value to nlfilter.